# Change Row background color based on cell value

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablerow

I need to change table row background color based on cell value,in this code i change table cell background color based on cell value.but i need to change entire row background color based on cell value.how can i do this...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').append('<div class="container" ><h4 style="color:#069">Batch-4 2nd Semester Timetable</h4></div><br>');

    var html = '<div class="container" ><table class="table table-striped"></div>';
    html += '<tr>';
    var flag = 0;

    var data2   =   <?php echo $valMS; ?>;
    $.each(data2[0], function(index, value){
        html += '<th>'+index+'</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';

     $.each(data2, function(index, value){

        html += '<tr>';

        $.each(value, function(index2, value2){

            if(value2 == "Java"){
                html += '<td style="background-color: #7e57c2;">'+value2+'</td>';
            }
            else{
                html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
            }
        });


        html += '</tr>';
     });


     html += '</table>';
     $('body').append(html);
     console.log(html);
});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this before the end of body

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".cell-java").parent().css("background-color","red");
});
</script>
```

modify your code to this so it will be add class "cell-java" to the td depending on it's value

```
  if(value2 == "Java"){
                    html += '<td style="background-color: #7e57c2;" class="cell-java">'+value2+'</td>';
                }
```

Comment: if(value2 == "Java"){
                html += '<td style="background-color: #7e57c2;" class="cell-java">'+value2+'</td>'; ?> <script>$(".cell-java").parent().css("background-color","red");</script> <?php 
            }
            else{
                html += '<td>'+value2+'</td>';
            }
        });

Comment: Code is not clear :( plz put code to your answer,don't provide it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you have a `parent()` method. Take a look at [this Demo](https://jsbin.com/medaji/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
var allCells = $(".row > div");

$.each(allCells, function (index, child) {
    if (child.textContent === "Desired value") {
        $(child).parent().css("background-color", "red");
    }

});
```

First I look for all the children (cells) of a `.row` class and assign them to the variable `allCells`.

Next I iterate over all of them and check, if their text is matching: `child.textContent === "Desired value"`.

If it is matching, then I change its parent css: `$(child).parent().css("background-color", "red");`

Comment: Sorry I'm confused with this,can you edit my code :(